# using both api gateway and message broker in microservice

Tags: microservices

I have a question about microservice implementation. right now I am using an api gateway to process all get request to my individual services and using kafka to handle asynchronous post put and delete request. Is this a good way of handling of handling request in a microservice architecture?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.nginx.com/blog/building-microservices-free-ebook-oreilly-nginx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too unspecific to give a good answer. What is a `good` architecture totally depends on the details of your use cases. Are you serving web pages, streaming media, amass data for analysis, or something completely different? We would also need to know what are you requirements in terms of concurrency, consistency and scalability? What are the constraints for budget/size of development teams, ease of development, dev skills, etc?

For example the decisions you have taken may be considered `good` if you have strong requirements for a highly scalable input of large data sets and very frequent data collection as well as the team to support it. But it may be considered `bad` if you have a small team only and are trying to get a quick and cheap MVP for a new service that has limited scalability requirements (because the complexity of the solution slows down your development unnecessarily).

It may be `good` because the development team is familiar with those technologies and can effectively develop with those. Or it may be `bad` because your team does not know anything about those and the investment in learning those will not be justifiable by long term gains.

Don't forget that one of the ideas of the microservices architectural style is that each service can be owned by a distinct team that makes its own decisions about what technology to use for implementation (for whatever reason: ease of development, business reasons etc). So in other words the microservices style embraces the old [wisdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_law) `architecture follows organization`.

Here a [link to a recommended further read](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html).